# iOS background notification not receiving on one app

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have a real head scratcher here.

My company sells 2 apps created with Expo. Both are the same app, but one is white labeled. This means the color scheme and the provisioning are different, but the code/permissions/API are exactly the same.

On my iphone, I installed both apps (A and B). App A is receiving both foreground and background notifications. App B is receiving only foreground notifications.

I am using RNFirebase to get a FCM token and I send this to the API. Then, I use `react-native-notifications` to register and create event listeners.

Here are my listeners:

```js
import {Notifications} from 'react-native-notifications';

Notifications.events().registerNotificationReceivedForeground((notification, completion) => {
    console.log('foreground notification', notification);
    completion({alert: false, sound: false, badge: false});
});
Notifications.events().registerNotificationReceivedBackground((notification, completion) => {
    console.log('background notification', notification);
    completion({alert: false, sound: false, badge: false});
});
```

For App A I get:

```
foreground notification [Object object]
background notification [Object object]
```

For App B I get:

```
foreground notification [Object object]
```

I did some extra checks;

- checking if the permissions are all the same
- the Apple Identifier has the correct capabilities
- the JSON request to firebase is correct
- content-available = 1 in de aps body

All seems fine.

The above results tell me that there is nothing wrong with my server code and that the client code should be working as well.

Does anybody have an idea where to start looking? (I already rebooted the phone)

Comment: I found that 2 other devices did not show  this behaviour. Reinstalling the entire iphone did resolve the symptoms.

Comment: I have the same problem and it seems to me that no one has found the solution.